# what is '*' in ASP.NET MVC 4 Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

What does the `*` in the line:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

mean?

Does it mean "match everything that looks like: `{resource}.axd/1/2/3/4/5` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard provides a catch-all route. It allows, as you assume, any number of paramters after the wildcard parameter:

> AnyResource.axd/any/number/of/parameters/will/be/valid

It's also useful when creating a CMS and you want process the url yourself rather than using static routing parameters. Example:

```
"{*slug}"
```

You could create a lookup table in your database and retrieve the specific page for the provided slug.

Comment: This is precisely for a CMS